# Sorting with a custom AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, jtable

I've made my own class which extends AbstractTableModel. The idea is to be able to store a hidden "id" collumn. The following code works well for this purpose:

```
public class GuiTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {


List<Object[]> rowlist = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
List<String> colNames = new ArrayList<String>();

public void addRow(Object[] data) {
    rowlist.add(data);
}
public void addColumn(String name) {
    colNames.add(name);
}

public int getColumnCount() { 
    return colNames.size();
}

public int getRowCount() { 
    return rowlist.size();
}

public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
   return rowlist.get(row)[col];
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return colNames.get(column);
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int mColIndex) {
    return false;
}
```

As you can see above, its a very simple implementation. The problem is though, when someone sorts by column by clicking the column title in the JTable, the lists in the AbstractTableModel don't get updated. I need the lists to be in sync with the visual layout.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is though, when someone sorts by column by clicking the column title in the JTable, the lists in the AbstractTableModel don't get updated

And that is exactly the way it should work. The data in the model should never change when you do a sort or reorder columns. Its only the view that changes.

If you want to get data from the table then you should be using:

```
table.getValueAt(row, column)
```

and it will get you the proper value. If you need to get data from the model directly then you need to use:

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(row), column);
```

> The idea is to be able to store a hidden "id" collumn.

There is no reason to create a custom model for this. Just store all the data in the DefaultTableModel. Then you can remove the "ID" column from the view of the table.

```
table.getColumnModel().removeColumn( table.getColumn("ID") );
```

In this case the data in not in the view so you can't use table.getValueAt(...). Instead you must use table.getModel().getValueAt(...);

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using String rt = (String)model.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow()) But also thanks for the tip on not needing to use my own model!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `JTable.convertRowIndexToModel` as outlined at [JTable's and DefaultTableModel's row indexes lose their synchronization after I sort JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036156/jtables-and-defaulttablemodels-row-indexes-lose-their-synchronization-after-i-s)

Also, for more complicated sorting and filtering, try http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, а good solution of your problem is the observer pattern
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

your class has to implement observer interface to keep track of events that user generate by clicking on column title

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [JXTable](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18819.html) ? You can find it [here](http://swinglabs.org/)